# RTL captions with newfloat?

Tags: xetex, floats, polyglossia, right-to-left, bidi

Is it that the `float` package begins to show its age? I cannot get it to work right with XeLaTeX. Here is an example:

```
\documentclass{article} % compile with xelatex
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{polyglossia} 
  \setmainlanguage{hebrew} 
  \setotherlanguage{english}
  \newfontfamily\hebrewfont[Script=Hebrew]{Ezra SIL}% or{SBL Hebrew}

\newfloat{thingy}{htbp}{lot}[section]
\begin{document}
  \begin{thingy}
    \[ E = m c^2 \]
    \begin{hebrew}\setRTL\caption{This caption should be set RTL}\end{hebrew}
 \end{thingy}
\end{document}
```

[image: caption is not laid-out right-to-left as it should]

Comment: AFAIK this has nothing to due with "age", but is due to way `float` is processing the `\caption`'s in general. Apparently it stores the caption and places it depending on the layout of this float time. This also makes the position of `\caption` irrelevant.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Version 1.1.6 of the [`bidi`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/bidi) package (available today on CTAN and perhaps tomorrow by updating TeXLive 2010) adds support for the `float` package and hence captions inside RTL mode will be RTL and captions inside LTR mode will be LTR. Your code should be changed into:

```
\documentclass{article} % compile with xelatex
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{polyglossia} 
  \setmainlanguage{hebrew} 
  \setotherlanguage{english}
  \newfontfamily\hebrewfont[Script=Hebrew]{Ezra SIL}% or{SBL Hebrew}

\newfloat{thingy}{htbp}{lot}[section]
\begin{document}
  \begin{thingy}
    \[ E = m c^2 \]
    \caption{This caption should be set RTL}
 \end{thingy}
\end{document}
```

So this clearly means that you do not need to surround `\caption` by a `hebrew` environment and `\setRTL` command.

Comment: a tip: you can use backticks `\`` to mark your inline code as I did in my edit.

Comment: thanks for acting so quickly on this. I am currently in the process of installing TeX live 2010 to see whether it works for me.

Comment: I finally managed to install TeX live 2010, and with version 1.1.16, polyglossia 2010/07/15 v1.2.0, the caption is still problematic, the caption is still LTR.

Comment: Yossi Gil: No, it is not. Perhaps you can email me  your tex file, the pdf output and your log file. My email address should be in bidi documentation. Also note than in your example here, you only use English words not Hebrew ones and so the direction of each English word will be LTR. This is done by ICU. I need to see an example where you only have used bidi and float packages, so no polyglossia.